# Is it possible to get Private callers' number

Tags: android

I have a quick and simple question..

I'm working on a Phone app as we speak, and during that, I'm reading the recent calls' logs.
I wondered if it's possible to get the number from callers that call privately.

I asked my friend to call me, and it showed up as "-1"

```
12-13 20:33:13.463: I/System.out(13128): Call Details :
12-13 20:33:13.463: I/System.out(13128): Phone Number:--- -1 
12-13 20:33:13.463: I/System.out(13128): Call Type:--- MISSED 
12-13 20:33:13.463: I/System.out(13128): Call Date:--- Fri Dec 13 20:32:05 CET 2013 
12-13 20:33:13.463: I/System.out(13128): Call duration in sec :--- 0
```

So, Does anyone know if it INDEED Is possible?

I understand that it mostly has to do with the phone companies.. But I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. If you're the phone company. Feel free to read up on SS7 though. Telcordia books will make you sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly it isn't possible. Caller ID information is transmitted from the phone provider, and if it's private they will not pass it along to the device. In the API, it will be `-1` or other similar values.

There are third party demasking services out there. But they are apart of the actual phone system and essentially, they don't honor the private caller ID request.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a confirmation is all I needed.

(Can accept your answer in 10 minutes.)

Comment: Actually, if you subpoena the phone company you can determine the OPC (originating point code) given the DPC (destination point code) and approximate time of the call. Therefore it is indeed possible, just not with an API call.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks Elliot, Much Appreciated. Nawh, I'm not going in too deep. I just wondered that if It's possible, I could've added that "Function" into the app as well. Thanks for your Replies!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch or if you have a friend at the NSA...